# Error in Apache Spark called input path does not exist

Tags: hadoop

Are there any algorithms in Apache Spark to find out the frequent patterns in a text file. I tried following example but always end up with this error:

> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:
>   /D:/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/data/mllib/sample_fpgrowth.txt

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth

val transactions = sc.textFile("...").map(_.split(" ")).cache()

val model = new FPGrowth()

model.setMinSupport(0.5)

model.setNumPartitions(10)

model.run(transactions)

model.freqItemsets.collect().foreach { 
    itemset => println(itemset.items.mkString("[", ",", "]") + ", " + itemset.freq)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
file://D:/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/data/mllib/sample_fpgrowth.txt
```

or

```
D:/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/data/mllib/sample_fpgrowth.txt
```

if not work, replace `/` with `//`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running spark on windows.

Use file path like

```
D:\spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6\bin\data\mllib\sample_fpgrowth.txt
```

NOTE : Escape "\" if necessary .